# android - How to design the mapping class for gson

Tags: android, gson

if my  WS is success then get the following response

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","reason":"User phrase returned successfully.","response":{"isValidUser":"1","Phrase":"montu"}}
```

if same WS fails then get the following response

```
{"status":"FAILED","reason":"Invalid Username","response":false}
```

Here i am using gson for mapping.

Mapping class is

```
class HomeScreenUserResponse extends Object {
  public String status;
  public String reason;
  public checkUser response;
}

class checkUser {
  String isValidUser;
  String Phrase;
}
```

But this mapping is not working if web service is failed. It works only for ws success.
How to design the single mapping class for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
class Class {
  boolean status;
  String reason;
  Responce responce;

  public Class(JSONObject jObject) {
    status = jObject.getString("status").equals("SUCCESS") ? true : false;
    reason = jObject.getString("reason");
    if (status) {
      responce = new Responce(jObject.getJSONObject("response"));
    } else {
      responce = null;
    }
  }
}

class Responce{
  String isValidUser;
  String Phrase;
  public Responce(JSONObject jObject){
   //Loading json data
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that'll work. Gson can't handle an object that's deserialized from different types.

Answer (score 0):

You should register a custom type adapter for this type. You'll want to inspect the value of "response" and behave differently depending on whether that's an object or a boolean.